# Unable to set focus of an element

Tags: wpf, textbox, stackpanel, expander, focusmanager

I have an Expander that its content consists of a `StackPanel` that contains several elements one of whom is a `TextBox`.

I want, that when the `Expander` expands that `TextBox` should gain keyboard focus, how do I do this?

I tried:

```
Private Sub xp_Expanded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) _
    Handles xpUnits.Expanded
        stackPanel.Focus()
        Keyboard.Focus(textBox)
  textBox.Focus()
End Sub
```

I even tried to set `FocusManager.IsFocusable` and `FocusManager.FocusedElement` to the `TextBox`, then call `stackPanel.Focus()`, but it didn't do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your `TextBox` is not yet visible when you try to set the focus. You should add an event handler for `IsVisibleChanged` to your `TextBox` and set the focus there. Inside `xp_Expanded` you just should set a boolean flag that the `TextBox` should be focused the next time the `IsVisibleChanged` event handler is called.

Comment: It works, but isn't there a more elegant way to do this the xaml way, or not having to add handlers for this IsVisible property of the TextBox?

Comment: It's very odd, why isn't the tb visible at the expanded event??

Comment: The TextBox is not yet visible, because at the time when the `Expanded` event handler runs, the TextBox is still in the process of being made visible. Instead of a IsVisibleChanged event handler you can use something like `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(Window1.SetFocusToTextBoxAsync), textBox);` which is likely to run after the TextBox has become visible.

Comment: This worked for me nicely. Might not be the cleanest way, but after a couple of hours of frustration it looks like the perfect, cleanest and most beautiful solution everrrr...eeeeeeeverrr #okNot :D

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218718/xamly-set-keyboard-focus-to-an-element-in-datagridtemplatecolumn-cell/4218732#4218732) solved my issue easily:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Title}"
  FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me, the effect was to have the expander automatically expanded but the textbox didn't have the focus. I tried @fmunkert solution and worked well. :)