# Xamly set keyboard focus to an element in DataGridTemplateColumn cell?

Tags: wpf, xaml, keyboard, focus, focusmanager

I've set stuff in a DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditing DataTemplate.
I want that when the cell editing loads and shows the template, keyboard-focus should be given to a certain control in the template.

Consider this example, when you go edit mode, the textbox is not keyboard-focused:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Title">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Note}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding Note}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>      
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
Class MainWindow 

  Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object,
                            ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded

    Dim data As New List(Of Item) From
      {New Item,
       New Item,
       New Item}
    dg.ItemsSource = data
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class Item
  Private Shared Number As Integer = 0
  Sub New()
    Number += 1
  End Sub
  Public Property Title = "Title " & Number.ToString
  Public Property Note = "Note " & Number.ToString
End Class
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well answer was actually simple, the above textboxes should be changed as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Title}"
  FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Note}"
  FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```